# XAML DataContext and ViewModel Type

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use MVVM for my application, the `DataContext` of controls is assigned in my c# code (not in XAML).

Therefore the XAML controls have no idea to which instance type its `DataContext` is set to. The consequence is that there is no refactoring support and intellisense for the bound properties of my viewmodel in XAML.

Is there a way to tell a control in XAML to which type its `DataContext` is linked?

So when I modify a property name in my ViewModel or search for all references of that property, I want that this property in XAML bindings gets considered too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no framework support, the best you can do is tell the VS designer the 'shape' of the DataContext so that it will give you hints for the properties. If you want to make your solution more refactor-proof, I would recommend Daniel's T4 metadata solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/T4Metadata.aspx

This generatesmetadata for your view models which you can reference in the XAML:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Person}}">
   <TextBlock >Name:</TextBlock>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path={x:Static Metadata:PersonMetadata.NamePath}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Colin E.

Answer (score 2):

No, as the DataContext can change at runtime, it doesn't make sense to tie this to a particular type.

Comment: while this may be true, i have a lot of cases where a control is linked to one particular viewmodel type

Comment: I disagree. It wouldn't make sense to switch the DataContext between incompatible types as you wouldn't know what to bind to... even many TemplateSelector implementations rely on types. And e.g. in Razor you have a feature for this - the model of a view is `dynamic` by default, but you can provide a type via the `@model` directive to get proper IntelliSense.